# PHP: How do I compare values in nested associative arrays?

Tags: php, wordpress, compare, associative-array, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to accomplish this…

I have an that's something like:

```
$contributors = array(
[0] => array(
    [name] => 'John',
    [role] => 'author',
    ),
[1] => array(
    [name] => 'Gail',
    [role] => 'author',
    ),
[2] => array(
    [name] => 'Beth',
    [role] => 'illustrator',
    ),
)
```

I'm trying to use this information to construct a detailed byline, like:

> Written by John and Gail. Designed by Beth.

I need to compare each `role` to the previous and next ones in order to:

1. Use a label  before the first instance of each `role`
2. Separate multiple instances of the same `role` with a comma
3. Use "and" instead of a comma before the last instance of each `role`

I'm no PHP expert so I'm having a hard time figuring out how to approach this! I have a function to output the right label depending on the `role`, but it's the comparisons I can't seem to figure out. I've considered `foreach` and `while` loops, but neither seems up to the job. I've never used a `for` loop so I don't know if it applies.

Some additional background:

- I'm working with WordPress and the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.
- `$contributors` is the value of an [ACF Repeater](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/) field, where `name` and `role` are subfields. (I've simplified the names to make things easier.)

Comment: Do you only have two roles, author and illustrator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group the array per role and use `array_pop` to remove the element. `implode` the remaining array elements and just append the *popped value*.

```
$contributors = array(
    array(
        "name" => 'John',
        "role" => 'author',
        ),
    array(
        "name" => 'Gail',
        "role" => 'author',
        ),
    array(
        "name" => 'Jose',
        "role" => 'author',
        ),
    array(
        "name" => 'Thomas',
        "role" => 'author',
        ),
    array(
        "name" => 'Beth',
        "role" => 'illustrator',
        ),
    array(
        "name" => 'Mary',
        "role" => 'producer',
        ),
    array(
        "name" => 'Criss',
        "role" => 'producer',
        ),
);

//Grouped the names according to role
$grouped = array_reduce($contributors, function($c, $v) {
    if ( !isset( $c[ $v['role'] ] ) ) $c[ $v['role'] ] = array();
    $c[ $v['role'] ][] = $v['name'];
    return $c;
}, array());


//Construct final Array
$final = array();
foreach( $grouped as $key => $group ) {
    $last = array_pop( $group );

    if ( count( $group ) == 0 ) $final[ $key ] = $last; /* One one name on the role, no need to do anything*/
    else $final[ $key ] = implode( ", ", $group ) . " and " . $last;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $final );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [author] => John, Gail, Jose and Thomas
    [illustrator] => Beth
    [producer] => Mary and Criss
)
```

You can now use it as

```
echo 'Written by ' . $final["author"] . '. Designed by ' . $final["illustrator"] . '. Produced by ' . $final["producer"];
```

And will result to:

> Written by John, Gail, Jose and Thomas. Designed by Beth. Produced by
>   Mary and Criss

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! Fairly simple (though I had to look up `array_reduce` to understand what was going on) and I was able to modify it for more complex uses.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this -

```
$contributors = array(
  array(
    'name' => 'John',
    'role' => 'author',
  ),
  array(
    'name' => 'Gail',
    'role' => 'author',
  ),
  array(
    'name' => 'Ali',
    'role' => 'author',
  ),
  array(
    'name' => 'Beth',
    'role' => 'illustrator',
  )
);

#This function prepare array to expected String
function PrepareArray($data){
  $combined = '';
  if (count($data)>1) {
    $last       = array_slice($data, -1);
    $first      = join(', ', array_slice($data, 0, -1));
    $both       = array_filter(array_merge(array($first), $last), 'strlen');
    $combined   = join(' and ', $both);
  }else{
    $combined = implode('', $data);
  }
  return $combined;
}

$authors    = array();
$designers  = array();

foreach ($contributors as $key => $value) {
  if ($value['role']=='author') {
    $authors[]      = $value['name'];        #Keep Authors name in Array
  }else if ($value['role']=='illustrator') {
    $designers[]    = $value['name'];            #Keep Designers name in Array
  }
}

$authors    = PrepareArray($authors);
$designers  = PrepareArray($designers);

echo "Written by {$authors}. Designed by {$designers}.";
```

**Output :**

> Written by John, Gail and Ali. Designed by Beth.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<?php

$contributors = array(
  0 => array(
    'name' => 'John',
    'role' => 'author',
  ),
  1 => array(
    'name' => 'Gail',
    'role' => 'author',
  ),
  2 => array(
    'name' => 'Beth',
    'role' => 'illustrator',
 ),
 3 => array(
    'name' => 'Albert',
    'role' => 'author',
 ),
);


$labels = ['author'=>'Written by', 'illustrator'=>'Designed by', 'producer'=>'Produced by'];

$new_contributors = [];

foreach($contributors as $cont){
    $new_contributors[$cont['role']][] = $cont['name'];
}
$str = '';
foreach($labels as $role=>$label){
  if(isset($new_contributors[$role]) && is_array($new_contributors[$role])){
    $str .= ' '.$label.' ';
    foreach($new_contributors[$role] as $key=>$new_contributor){
        $count = count($new_contributors[$role]);
        if(($count - $key) == 1 ){
            $str .= ' and ';
            $str .= $new_contributor;
        }else if(($count - $key) == 2){
            $str .= $new_contributor;
        }else{
            $str .= $new_contributor.', ';
        }
    }
  }

}

echo $str;
```